# Sending Emails in android app

Tags: android, email

I am working on an andriod app, my client's requirement is to add a "Forgot Password" page in app, this page ask user to enter his email, if email is authenticated then App should email the password to user email.

I am looking for online Email server and have no idea to do this.

Scenario is just simple, the app should able to send email with private email account (for example `XXXX@App.com`)

Comment: this is the best way to make your app marked as spam, if you want to send emails to your users buy your own SMTP server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `javax.mail` API to send e-mails. Remember that sending e-mails requires you to have an SMTP server, but you can use GMail's SMTP server as a start. A sample code can be found here:

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=144

Just remember about couple of things:

- You *should not* send emails from your Android application. Since you must provide an SMTP server and its account credentials, they could be stripped from your application code and abused.
- You should put the email-sending code in your server and allow it to only send a couple of message types (e.g. password recovery helper, subscription notification, etc.) based on message type and some other needed data (like user ID) sent from your application. This protects you from the possibility that someone will use your server to send arbitrary messages (e.g. regular spam).
- You must provide valid credentials instead of `fromblah@blah.com` and configure your email settings. For example GMail uses custom port for SMTP server. You can find help here: http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78775

Comment: Thanks, There is another problem that will be faced, Google block email address when its accessed from multiple places at the same time, It this smtp case, is this happens again or Email will not blocked whatever its accessed from multiple places at same time?????

Comment: Like I said - if it's placed in your server which your app is requesting to send an email then no, it won't be blocked.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"youremail@app.com"});        
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "message");
    email.setType("message/rfc822");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
```

Source  : [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-send-email-in-android/).

**P.S. :** You should buy an SMTP server to send users emails from your app.

Comment: Thanks, is there any online email server exist? means i just create an account there, they provide me the APIs and i just call through API and the server send my email... Hope its clear!

Comment: Have a look at this : http://www.postcastserver.com/

Comment: http://www.e-eeasy.com/SMTPServerList.aspx

Comment: Thanks, There is another problem that will be faced, Google block email address when its accessed from multiple places at the same time, It this smtp case, is this happens again or Email will not blocked whatever its accessed from multiple places at same time?????

Comment: Nopes, it wont be blocked if it's your own SMTP server.